# Why Stock dividend yield (TTM) is different from Yield (FWD)

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis

Here is what confuses me.Example: CTRA stock (Coterra Energy Inc.) I read [about it](https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/CTRA) in Seeking Alpha and checking "Dividend Yield" chart I see this:
[image]

While at the "Summary" page I see this:

[image]

As an owner of this stock I have received the quarter dividend which actually seems to be $0.15, which makes sense according to $0.60 annual dividend per share. If so, what does **9.13** in the dividend yield chart mean? What is the figure I should look at when I want to learn what is the real annual dividend of the stock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at their investor relations website they have paid 4 dividends of around $.60 in the last 12 months: https://investors.coterra.com/Investors/dividend-history/default.aspx. Take the total of those dividends ($2.49) and divide by yesterday's closing price of 27.26 and you should get 9.1343% rounding to 9.13%. If just happens that the dividends are broken down into two parts - an interim (or final) payment for each quarter of $.15 and an "extra" dividend of around $.50 which obfuscates this (since $.15 * 4 = 60, any other number would have been helpful).

You can see the dividend broken down here: https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/ctra/dividend-history

Comment: Now it makes sense to me. I was also wondering about that "extra" dividend and why it appears as a separate figure in the dividend history.

Comment: @MichaelIV let's say that I don't think its a coincidence that the numbers add up the way that they do. If my answer was useful, helpful and potentially answered your question consider accepting the answer by pressing the little tick button under the voting arrows

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Yield (FWD) is the forward looking yield based on the expected EPS/dividend.

The TTM (trailing twelve months) yield is different, since it's backward-looking (by definition.)